# Date and time difference function for PHP 5.1

Tags: php, datetime

PHP 5.3.0+ has a `DateTime::diff` function: http://docs.php.net/datetime.diff

Unfortunately I am currently using the PHP 5.1 branch with no possibility to upgrade. So what is the best way to work out a date-time difference?

For example the time difference between `22-01-2013 17:00` and `23-01-2013 13:00`.

I am not really worried about the output format as such.

Comment: My exact PHP version is `5.1.6`

Comment: `$diff = abs(strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2)); echo date('desirable format here', $diff);`? _Note:_ to get differences in year, you should subtract 1970 from returned value. ;)

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa Are you kidding?!? You _definitely_ should upgrade, not just because `DateTime`!

Comment: @KingCrunch it depends. Redhat for example maintains a lot old php versions and pushes the bugfixes and security fixes into these versions. So if he has such a version, there is no security problem, just a feature-problem.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Something like this will remain hacks. And it is not possible to backport every security-fix. Not every patch is cleanly appliable and also the bugs may be in a used libary, that you cannot change so easily. It is _not_ just a feature-problem... And no, it even does not "depends" with such veeery old versions ;)

Comment: Just to clarify the comments above, the last release of PHP 5.1 was in August 2006 -- ie six and a half years ago. (see http://uk.php.net/releases/index.php).

Comment: I see a lot of people who post here saying they can't upgrade, but I would be interested to know what's stopping you. There really aren't that many issues moving from 5.1 to 5.3, especially if you ignore the deprecation warnings. But moving forward, the differences do get bigger: The longer you say I can't upgrade, the more of a reality it becomes. Read PHP's upgrade notes [here](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/migration52.incompatible.php) and [here](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php). Are you using any of those features? If not, please explain again why you can't upgrade

Comment: It's up to the company lol - but you're right that its worth testing to see if there are any issues and then upgrading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to know is `strtotime` php function.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

**Zend framework doesn't run on PHP 5.1 ... the last version which supports PHP 5.1 was Zend Framework 1.6 (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.6/en/requirements.version.html) but you shouldn't use it.**

If you want to have a nice interface, you can use Zend_Date.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.date.overview.html#id.date.basic.operations

If you want it fast and with php core, just use strtotime as @dipesh-parmar suggested

Comment: Doesn't work with 5.1 ;) At least it's not officially supported, but I can't (and will not) test it myself.

Comment: you are right. an option would be to use an older version... but this isn't a good idea :)

Comment: Who said anything about Zend? We're not using Zend framework, its just a bespoke PHP application, but thanks for the response! Will consider Zend_Date for a future Zend web app

Comment: no one said that. But it is the nearest alternative to DateTime if you ask me :)